# Rewriting url rule applied on a folder

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a url that looks like this : www.mysite.com/directory1/directory2/directory3 .

Using htaccess I want to define a rewrite rule to be able to redirect the last piece of the url which is in this example (directory3) to directory3.html

has anybody an idea  ?

Comment: So it should load content of `www.mysite.com/directory1/directory2/directory3.html` OR `www.mysite.com/directory3.html`?

Comment: the content of www.mysite.com/directory1/directory2/directory3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /RestAPI/

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/RestAPI/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

1. This rule captures whole URI except last optional slash in back-reference `$1`.
2. It constructs full filesystem path using `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/RestAPI/$1.html` where `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}` is internal `mod_rewrite` variable representing value of actual `DOCUMENT_ROOT` path in your system.
3. Using `-f` it checks whether this `.html` fils exists.
4. If condition is true it routes it to `.html` file.

Comment: thanks for it , I may have forgotten to mention that I want it to be dynamic , so it takes always the last directory name and load its equivalent html file

Comment: Oh thank you so much ... It would be really so great if you could just briefly explain what it does exactly ...and so sorry to bother you

Comment: in addition i tried it out and it's not working .. I get object not found .. this is the content of my htaccess file :   RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]    and this is the content of httpd.conf :    <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
</Directory>

Comment: well the .htaccess is in the root directory and yes , the directory3.html is a real file and it exists inside the directory2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67026/discussion-between-anubhava-and-rakibi-anass).

Comment: hey @anubhava : your code worked fine for me , I tried to implement it in a typo3 cms and I assume it's not working ... because of the Document Root , because the structure in it is different , now is there a possibility to make it work as well in my typo3 script . This its the File structure (on the server) : /freigegeben/htdocs

Comment: Just change `RestAPI` to whatever relative dir you have from `DocumentRoot`.

Comment: can I do it using the Http_host instead of Document root ?

Comment: No you cannot do that and I request please avoid extensive commenting. I have been cautioned by SO mods against it.